# How is recurrence approached in bug questions?

Tags: discussion

How does AU deal with the recurrence of bug questions if those are deleted. This will only drive people away because their question doesn't get nothing but deleted.

Comment: If what are deleted? We keep one, good, question for when a fix comes out and all other questions related to that bug get closed as a dupe or "Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues. "

Comment: What else can be deleted ? The questions ofc, OK So as a user we should tag those for development ? ( in the case we know it is a bug ) Or maybe we can start or there is already a Bug tag

Comment: No don't even ask them or close them (3k privilage) as "should be reported as a bug". We don't need a bug tag, we don't fix bugs, bugs should be reported to the developers so they can fix it. We find the bug reports and link them in a comment and close the question as a bug report or post a fix if one exists already and then just leave it open.

Comment: @MarkKirby Great, thanks.

Comment: @MarkKirby That sounds strangely like an answer.

Comment: @ThomasWard Done, I was on phone yesterday :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should close them (3k privilege) as "should be reported as a bug", if you don't have the rep to CV it, just leave a comment linking the bug tracker and a comment directing them there and others will close based on your comment.

You can just post fix if one exists already and then just leave it open as having the fix here is of course a good thing

We don't need a bug tag, we don't fix bugs, bugs should be reported to the developers so they can fix it.

If anyone wants to debate this policy or thinks it is unfair, you can do so at [this question about the policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15908/please-reconsider-closing-bug-related-questions-if-a-workaround-can-be-produced).